# How to compile BibTeX in PHP

Tags: math-mode, bibtex, greek, author, php

How BibTeX can be compiled in PHP? I have tried some PHP libraries, but the thing is that Latex works with Bibtex better I guess.

Can I automatically use Latex to parse the Bibtex and then my app to get the results back?

Can/Shall I integrate any Latex component into my app? Is it possible? or should I try something else?

I don't know to what kind of approach I should look at.
In my implementation, currently I have the following issues:

1. Math mode characters are not transformed by the library. When Greek letters are present (eg a title in Greek) the vast majority of the letters are not compiled (they are in math mode). Some though, compile, I don't know why...
2. Long names, which is authors that have a lot name parts, such as

> Ribeiro, Antonio Augusto Coppi Maciel

(this is one author).

Any suggestion/idea???

Thank you!

Comment: your question is completely unclear. Do you mean that you want php to run bibtex at the server or do you mean that you want to re-implement the bibtex program natively in php, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I assume that your use case is David's first scenario, that is, you want to use LaTeX and BibTex as the back end of a web server that creates documents of some sort. That should work in principle; I do that on a website of mine (though with Python rather than PHP). To debug your setup, make sure that your sample document compiles correctly when invoking LaTeX and BibTex on it manually. Next, make sure the user that your server runs as can compile the LaTeX stuff, too. After that, php's `exec` command or some such should succeed.

Comment: Are you really asking about PHP parsing a BibTeX database rather than BibTeX, which is a binary?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , the first option is what I was talking about. The second one although it is an option too, I guess it is not recommended as would require a lot of developing work I guess.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer , Yes, I want to use LateX and Bibtex as the back end , however, I would like to note that my app does not creates any documents, it is just managing citations. Your suggestions looks that it will do the job for me as well. Before I get into the php code, which command lines I shall use for testing this? I want to provide a bibtex file path to the command and get the final (as final as it can be) text for each tag (title, author etc). Thank you!

Comment: @cfr, I really don' t think I understand your question. I want to parse a Bibtex string like the following:  @article{peter1999consumer,
  title={Consumer behavior and marketing strategy},
  author={Peter, J Paul and Olson, Jerry Corrie and Grunert, Klaus G},
  year={1999},
  publisher={McGraw-hill London}
}  Although this is the ideal scenario, I guess it will not be a trouble to create a file out of this string and pass it to the command line.

Comment: your question still is completely unclear, php does not need to know anything about bibtex if you are just executing a command via a shell, but bibtex needs, as well as the bib file, an `aux` file generated by latex which specifies the citations used in a specific document. You have given no indication how php is being passed any of this information.

Comment: That would be a typical entry in a `.bib` database. BibTeX can parse a `.bib` database, but it is not the only programme which can do this. As @DavidCarlisle says, for BibTeX, you'd need an `.auz` from a compilation run, as well (I think) as a `.bst`. But that's just standard stuff. Presumably you're asking something else, though it isn't clear what.

Comment: BibTeX doesn't produce text for each tag. It produces a `.bbl` file which is a bibliography for a specific document, marked up in a way which LaTeX then understands when the document is recompiled. This is pretty much like the bibliography you'd write by hand using `thebibliography` environment. LaTeX takes care of the citations, as far as I know, since the keys for the entries are included in the `\bibitem`s in the `.bbl`. At least, I think so. I haven't used BibTeX for a while. You might be better off with Biber.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Sorry for not being clear. I will try to explain in more detail: The Bibtex is used for importing the citations in the app.I'm not generating any document in my app, I just create a reference list (through php). I need to get all the data of the Bibtex file and provide it to be PHP code. Does this make sense?

Comment: It might make sense but that functionality is not related to your question title  "compile bibtex" .  The bibtex program does not have a feature of producing a list of all citations in a bibtex file.

Comment: @cfr, I think that what I actually need is to get the final text strings of each tag (author, title etc) in the way they are presented after being recompiled by Latex.... I guess...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, The bibtex file will contain always just one citation. This bibtex file will contain markup symbols that Latex understands and manipulates. How can I get the final title, authors and etc after being recompiled by Latex (where the fields will have their final form ) For example instead of providing in my app the ...{\'{}A}$\gamma$$\gamma$$\varepsilon$$... to provide the ...ΑΓΓΕ...

Comment: There are a couple of PHP libraries for parsing BibTex files that you might want to look at. This one looks as if it might help you: https://people.mmci.uni-saarland.de/~jilles/prj/phpBibLib/

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing an answer because I have no rights to write a comment.

If you are using composer, I would recommend you to evaluate another library for parsing bibtex files in php: `renanbr/bibtex-parser` https://github.com/renanbr/bibtex-parser

Comment: The question does not ask for a parser of the BibTeX *input*, but for something that processes or potentially parses the BibTeX *output*.

Comment: Hello all. Yes, I'm the author of that tool.The reply I made should be a comment instead, but unfornetally I have no rigths to do that in this platform.